# Best (default) approach for aurelia databinding/gui element initialization

Tags: semantic-ui, aurelia

I'm playing around with Aurelia.js in combination with semantic-ui. 
Both framework have abilities to fill for instance "select" elements of html.
(Following the 2 "offical examples".)

The way of semantic would for instance be:

```
 (<any>$('#semanticSelect'))
      .dropdown({
          apiSettings: {
              url: '//api.semantic-ui.com/tags/{query}'
          }
      })
      ;
```

The way of Aurelia according to the sample would be with httpclient

```
users = [];


constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
http.configure(config => {
  config
    .useStandardConfiguration()
    .withBaseUrl('https://api.github.com/');
});
```

}

```
activate() {
return this.http.fetch('users')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(users => this.users = users);
```

}

and in html with

```
repeat.for="user of users"
```

and binding according to needs like

```
<div class="item" repeat.for="user of users" data-value.bind="user.id">${user.login}</div>
```

So now I'm a little bit confused what's the correct way to work with? Can anyone explain me what's the difference and what's the recommed way?
It's a primary question how GUI controls should be initialized -> by aurelia framwork methods or of semantic ui framework! I'm considering about performance, caching and safety. I have nowhere read how it's recommed to do.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Aurelia Semantic dropdown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31731478/aurelia-semantic-dropdown)

Comment: I've written a blog about creating custom elements for wrapping css frameworks here: http://davismj.me/blog/semantic-custom-element/

Answer (score -1):

If you are going to use a full framework like Aurelia, I would suggest to just use the Aurelia method since semantic-ui is only for view layout and css with some javascript components.

Comment: thanks, but do you prefer to use the semantic-ui js functions within a aurelia template to init the control (i would say its the hybrid way) or do you prefer to use only aurelia methods? because it would be possible to call the semantic-ui js method within activate of aurelia?!?

Comment: I prefer using only aurelia methods so that I don't mix in a lot of jquery code into my view-models, but this may not always possible. My rule of thumb is if it is possible then just use aurelia view/view-model refs to the semantic-ui components to call the component methods in aurelia and fall back to jquery if needed.

Comment: great thing about aurelia is i've found it pretty easy integrating 3rd party components, unlike in angular 1.x where writing directives to use 3rd party controls was very painful at times.